# Two random variables - prove or disprove

Tags: random-variables

I need to prove or disprove the following:
There exist two random variables $X,Y$ s.t:
$Var[X]=Var[Y]=2$
$Cov(X,Y)=4$

I tried to stick to the definitions here and couldn't find any contradiction.
$E[X^2]-(E[X])^2=E[Y^2]-(E[Y])^2=2$
$E[XY]-E[X]E[Y]=4$

Nothing out of the ordinary... is it?

Comment: You must either prove the statement, by demonstrating that two such variables exist; or disprove the statement, by fashioning an argument to show that two such variables cannot exist.

A hint: what is $\rm{Corr}(X,Y)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aren't the variances too low for the covariance? The correlation $\rho_{XY}$ has to be in $[-1,1]$.

$$ \rho_{XY} = \frac{Cov(X,Y)}{\sigma_X\sigma_Y} = \frac{4}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2}} = 2 > 1$$

Answer (score 2):

Cauchy-Schwarz says that
$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y)
&=\mathrm{E}\Big((X-\mathrm{E}(X))\;(Y-\mathrm{E}(Y))\Big)\\
&\le\mathrm{E}\left((X-\mathrm{E}(X))^2\right)^{1/2}\mathrm{E}\left((Y-\mathrm{E}(Y))^2\right)^{1/2}\\[2pt]
&=\sigma(X)\,\sigma(Y)
\end{align}
$$
which verifies TooTone's asssertion.

Comment: I'd never thought of Cauchy-Schwartz as applying to expectations (but the expectation is an integral and the integrand is a product).

Comment: @TooTone: math is cool, n'est-ce pas?

Comment: oui, funny you switched language because math seems a lot like a language to me, with all the pain of learning the grammar, but also the poetry that comes with it.